# Ruby HTTP does not properly verify certificates from Google

Tags: ruby, https, openssl

I just noticed that my Ruby code fails to verify certificates from Google (Facebook works fine, as well as plain HTTP).

```
✗ ruby -rnet/https -e "Net::HTTP.get URI('http://www.google.com')"
✗ ruby -rnet/https -e "Net::HTTP.get URI('https://www.facebook.com')"
✗ ruby -rnet/https -e "Net::HTTP.get URI('https://www.google.com')"  
/Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:583:in `start'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:478:in `get_response'
    from /Users/ephracis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:455:in `get'
```

I'm running ruby 2.2.2p95 on OS X 10.11.1.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. All three work fine with Ruby v2.2.3 with OS X 10.10.5. Perhaps your Google certificate isn't correct?

Comment: My guess is that it is related to the setup of openssl in homebrew. But I lack the necessary skills to properly troubleshoot the issue further.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more of a workaround than an answer but at least it solved my problem:

Installing ruby-head solved the problem:

```
rvm install ruby-head
rvm use ruby-head
```

I tried to do a reinstall of my current ruby, 2.2.2, and also tried to upgrade to 2.2.3 but I still got the same error. Current ruby head points to 2.3.0dev and that version seems to work fine for me.